# Ubuntu 20.04.1 doesn't use my Bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, hp

I can connect my Bluetooth headphones to my Laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. They even show up in the audio settings menu and I set them as the default output.

When I use the test that is integrated into that menu it still uses the laptops integrated audio device for output. So does every other application I have tested (Discord, Firefox).

What could be the cause of this issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried using `pavucontrol` to set the output device? This sometimes helps in situations like this. You can install it with the following command: `sudo apt install pavucontrol` Then, it should show up in your installed applications under "pulse audio volume control." Open this app and try setting the BT headphones as the output device from there.

Comment: I have the same issue. Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't pick up my headphones as a Bluetooth device, despite every other device in the house, and to next door/on the road in front of the house picking them up.

Comment: Even my aa battery finds my headphones.